# Create an iptables rule if the rule does not already exist

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, iptables

Hi I've created a script to setup Nagios on my remote servers.  My script checks iptables to see if a firewall rule already exists and then is **supposed** to add the rule if it's not already there.

Right now the script just echoes out the rule but it's not actually able to write it any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ssh -t -t root@$serverName << EOF
  service nrpe restart
  chkconfig nrpe on
  if [ "cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables | grep -- "5666"" != "-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT" ] ; then echo "iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT" ; fi
  service iptables save
  exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

check if rules exist and if not - then add it

iptables -C INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT || iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change

```
echo "iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT"
```

to

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT
```

You can leave `-s 0/0` out:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT
```

And it would make sense to consider what is the best position within `INPUT`. If this rule should be the fifth (instead of the first) then change the call to:

```
iptables -I 5 INPUT -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT
```

And

```
"cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables | grep -- "5666""
```

contains an error. The command

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables | grep -- "5666"
```

is not executed. You must add command substitution:

```
"$(cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables | grep -- "5666")"
```

Comment: Still not quite there I'm now getting "grep: /etc/sysconfig/iptables: No such file or directory".  I've changed my code to be ` if [ "$(grep 5666 /etc/sysconfig/iptables)" != "-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACC    EPT" ] ; then iptables -I INPUT 3 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT ; fi`

Comment: @bpal If a file doesn't exist then you can trivially not use it as a source for the data to be checked. You need `iptables -L INPUT -nv | grep ...` (and would have to adapt the `grep` search string) or (better): `iptables -C INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT`